# How to retrieve image from URL from Firebase Realtime Database in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, imageurl

I am trying to extract URL named "imageUrl" so as to retrieve the image from the URL from Firebase Realtime Database as seen below:

This is DB structure in Firebase Realtime Database:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6uAz.png)

I have this DB:

```
{
  "Image": {
    "01": {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "img1",
      "imageUrl": "https://www.pexels.com/photo/beach-calm-clouds-coast-457881/"
    },
    "02": {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "img2",
      "imageUrl": "https://www.pexels.com/photo/sea-beach-holiday-vacation-42151/"
    }
  }
}
```

This is an Activity in Android Studio:

```
    public class BigToePose extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context context;
    private ImageView img;

    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference mReference;
    private DatabaseReference childReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bigtoepose);

        context = this;
        img = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mReference = database.getReference();
        childReference = mReference.child("Image").child("01");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        childReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String url = dataSnapshot.child("imageUrl").getValue(String.class);
                Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(url)
                        .into(img);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I tried to execute this code as an activity to which to move from another activity in Android Studio, but it looks like the activity is not showing. How can I get it to work?

Comment: Please add a more detailed screenshot of your database structure.

Comment: As @AlexMamo said, we really need to see a bit more detail about your Firebase structure so please include that in the question. However, please do not include Firebase Database Structures as a link or image. Include code and structures as text so we don't have to retype it if we want to use it in an answer. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: Oh - it also appears you may be using an array to store your data. There are usually much better options for storing - see the legacy but still relevant blog post [Arrays Are Evil](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) for some other ideas.

Comment: I added json format structure as text.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are try to get the firebase reference's outside the executed methods, it might not get executed at all.
Try by changing the code as below :-

```
public class BigToePose extends AppCompatActivity {

private Context context;
private TextView url;
private ImageView img;

private FirebaseDatabase database ;
private DatabaseReference mReference ;
private DatabaseReference childReference ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bigtoepose);

    context = this;
    img = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

   // place here
   database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
   mReference = database.getReference("Image");
   childReference = mReference.child("01");
 }

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    childReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String message = dataSnapshot.child("imageUrl").getValue(String.class);
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(message)
                    .into(img);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I am sharing my example. See how it worked for me.

```
{"Questions": {
"1": {
  "question": "One MB is equal to",
  "option1": "1024KB",
  "option2": "1024Byte",
  "option3": "1000KB",
  "option4": "1024GB",
  "answer": "1024KB",
  "hint": "https://www.pexels.com/photo/123-let-s-go-imaginary-text-704767/"
},
"2": {
  "question": "What s used to make computer chips",
  "option1": "copper",
  "option2": "steel",
  "option3": "silicon",
  "option4": "iron",
  "answer": "silicon",
  "hint": "https://www.pexels.com/photo/grayscale-photography-of-railroad-crossing-signage-981294/"
}}}
```

See this is my code in Android Studio. But my Image is stored in firebase storage and your's on pixels. That's a difference.

```
public class Hint extends MainActivity {

private TextView url;
private ImageView img;
DatabaseReference childReference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hint);

    url = findViewById(R.id.mURLText);
    img = findViewById(R.id.mHintImage);

    childReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Questions").child("1").child("Hint");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    childReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            String message = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
            url.setText(message);
            Picasso.get()
                    .load(message)
                    .into(img);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}}
```

So in your case your code should be like this:

```
public class BigToePose extends AppCompatActivity {

private Context context;
private ImageView img;

private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference mReference;
private DatabaseReference childReference;
private Int url; // for a new TextView you'll have to create which I've mentioned below

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bigtoepose);

    context = this;
    url = findViewById(R.Id.mURLText); // you will have to add a textView in your XML file and initiate it here, like I did here
    img = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mReference = database.getReference();
    childReference = mReference.child("Image").child("01").child(imageUrl);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    childReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String message = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            url.setText(message);
            Picasso.get()
                    .load(message)
                    .into(img);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
  }
}
```

I hope it's helpful for you.